# Checking if any button is clicked in javascript

Tags: javascript, click

I am working at a rubik's cube html site and I ought to mention I am a beginner. What I want to do now is to check if any piece (I have created 54 divs with the same class) is clicked and if so to change its color (modifying the div's background). I ask you if there is any method that can make my task easier or at least give me a piece of advice. Thank you in advance!

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 1):

As a simple method, you could write a function to accept the reference to a div and change its color whenever a div is clicked and call it on each div's onClick method.

Code:

```html
<html>
  <body>
  <div id="div1" onClick="changeMyColor(this)">
  Here is the div, click on this to change the color
  </div>

    <script>
      function changeMyColor(div) {
        div.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
      }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### Edit

In your case, you could do something similar to the following with the help of jQuery. Notice that this is a simplified answer and you could extend it depending on what exactly needs to be done.

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="divs">Click Me [Div 1]</div>
    <div class="divs">Click Me [Div 2]</div>
    <div class="divs">Click Me [Div 3]</div>
  </body>
  
  <script>
    $(".divs").click(function() {
      $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: edited the previous comment and replaced some parts of the code in a way you can easily do it

Comment: So am I supposed to write the name of that function and use onclick 54 times ?

Comment: Well, I mentioned that this is a simplified answer. For your specific case, you could add the same class name for all 54 divs and write an onClick event listener for elements with that same class. Within the function, you could retrieve the clicked div element and change its color.

Comment: @StefanMIhai consider the "edit" section of the answer as the answer to the question "So am I supposed to write the name of that function and use onclick 54 times". There could be easier solutions in vanilla JS as well. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use some keyboard/mouse events.
Check them out : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeydown.asp